# How to do a simple XAML (WPF) conditional binding on the Visibility property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got a view model with a property:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
}
```

I want to use this property to toggle a button state. If the boolean is true I want to hide the button, and otherwise show it.

I tried things like:

```
<Button Visibility= "{Binding IsEnabled ? Hidden : Visible  }">Enable</Button>
```

But this doesn't fit.

I tried some more complex solution but my guess is, I am missing something trivial.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add a Bool  to visibility converter

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since you want to toggle between `Hidden` and `Visible` and true is hidden you can either write custom `IValueConverter` or use simple `Style.Trigger`

```
<Button Content="Enable">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>                    
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

This is all assuming the `DataContext` is set accordingly and `MyModel.IsEnabled` raises `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event whenever changed

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isEnabled;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This is great, I learned a lot from your answer. Is the `<DataTrigger ` a general (best-practices) way of modifying properties of xaml elements with this kind of specific logic?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes the relation between source and target is more complex and you need to write  either `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` but if you have one value, from whole range of source property values, when something should happen - in your case when true then Hidden - it's easier to use `DataTrigger`

Answer (score 27):

Use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Button Visibility= "{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same because BooleanToVisbilityConverter returns Collapsed (not Hidden) for a false value. The OP has the boolean switched as well, so true should map to Hidden and false to Visible

Comment: Besides true would mean Visible and not Hidden/Collapsed

Comment: And the op needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well :)

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Add a class inheriting IValueConverter

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool)value;
        if (bValue)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;

        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: There is now a built-in [BooleanToVisibilityConverter class in System.Windows.Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter) that does this.