# Disable/Enable ComboBox-Items depending on selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have following ViewModel:

```
 private MovementType selectedMovementType = MovementType.Continous;
 private bool isMovementSelectable;
 private readonly DeviceSelection DeviceSelection;

 public AxisActionsViewModel(...)
 {
     ....
     this.isMovementSelectable = false;
     this.DeviceSelection.Devices.CollectionChanged
        += this.Devices_CollectionChanged;
     ....
 }


  public bool IsMovementSelectable
  {
     get => this.isMovementSelectable;

     set
     {
        this.isMovementSelectable = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
     }
  }

  private void Devices_CollectionChanged(
     object sender,
     System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {

      if (this.transportDeviceSelection.TransportDevices.Any(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains("a"))
        || this.transportDeviceSelection.TransportDevices.Any(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains("b")))
     {
        this.IsMovementSelectable = false;
     }
     else
     {
        this.IsMovementSelectable = true;
     }
  }

  public IEnumerable<MovementType> MovementTypes
  {
     get
     {
        yield return MovementType.Continous;
        yield return MovementType.Relative;
        yield return MovementType.Absolute;
     }
  }

  public MovementType SelectedMovementType
  {
     get => this.selectedMovementType;

     set
     {
        if (this.selectedMovementType != value)
        {
           this.selectedMovementType = value;

           this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedMovementType);

           this.UpdateMovementTemplate();
        }
     }
  }
```

and in the View the binding to the IsMovementSelectable Property of the ViewModel

```
 <UIComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MovementTypes}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovementType}">

           <UIComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="UIComboBoxItem">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                         Value="{Binding IsMovementSelectable}"/>
              </Style>
           </UIComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

My question is now, how do I implement this functionality correctly? 
I want that the ComboBox consists only of specific items when A or B are selcted.
Where do I have put the IsMovementSelectable property in order to get the wanted behaviour?
I tried different approaches but none lead to a positive result.

Comment: the simplest way would be to use a collection view to filter the item source of the combo this would then remove any invalid values before they are passed to the combo

Comment: I think, your conception went wrong way. 1. You compare string.tolowercase with some upperCase char like 'A'. 2.foreach device you'r turning same value on and off, so the IsMovementSelectable depends only on last device. 3.You'r looking for IsMovementSelectable in each ComboboxItem in it's dataContext, that mean, because your dataContext of these items is just enum value, setter won't work. So if you want to disable all items, just use relativeSource. If you want to have enable/disable different items, you need to redesign some things: You need some dataModel with Value and bool properties.

Comment: I was editing the code before posting it and removed some unnecessary parts...of course in my code I use only lowerCase in the Contains()...I already made some changes regarding your #2 checking the list with .Any...for #3 I think you are right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike commented, the best would be if you just filter what ends up in your ComboBox, take a look [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html).
`CollectionView` can easily take care of what you need to do, just create one and bind your `ItemsSource` to it.

You *might* be able to maintain your current approach, and use a hack to get the desired behavior, by using the Visibility Property:

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsMovementSelectable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

You would need to create a `BoolToVisibilityConverter` converter, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172550).
This is not tested, and I have no clue what result you might get, but if you don't want or can't re-write your code properly, this might do the trick. If you are lucky it will collapse the Items that shouldn't be displayed.