# How to hide uwp, similar to the this.Hide() function of WinForm application

Tags: c#, uwp

How to hide uwp, similar to the this.Hide() function of WinForm application, can control display and hide through combination keys.

Comment: You mean: hide the whole application / window? Or minimize it to the task bar? Or hide an element. For this last case see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172392/how-to-do-a-simple-xaml-wpf-conditional-binding-on-the-visibility-property#30172553

Comment: @Stefan What I want to  hide the whole application / window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to hide the whole application / window

Unfortunately, UWP doesn't contain such a feature. UWP is designed to be a UI display client project.

Check UWP relative features that doesn't require  UI showing if they can meet your detail requirements. For example, [background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks).

Comment: I found a new problem. If  use appService, there is no whole application / window, but it won't pop up the interface to login to Microsoft account. What I want to do now is to minimize the execution of uwp, not directly on the desktop, but I don't know how to minimize to the taskbar.

Comment: Minimize cannot be programmed currently either. See https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18076333-allow-an-window-to-minimize-programatically. For "but it won't pop up the interface to login to Microsoft account.", please describe more about your actual problem, for example, what are you developing, what's the problem when you implement which feature and so on. You could ask a new thread with these information I mentioned.

Comment: We develop applications for OneDrive, one of which is that users need to log in to Microsoft's account to be used. When you get token through API, a Microsoft login window is popped out normally, but when the uwp window is not displayed, it will not pop up a Microsoft login window, so we want to minimize the execution of uwp.