# Is there any way to check for a condition in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a Datagrid in which data comes from Database based on some selection and therefore the values keep on changing at different selections.

On the basis of the data, I want to add a TextBox to the UI?

This is .NET framework 4.5

```
<DataGrid Name="Sampledatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="`{StaticResource MyCustomers}" Margin="0,0,0,106"/>

<Canvas>
    <br/>
    <!-- if Sampledatagrid.Value == 'Adam' -->
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="12" Style={StaticResource textboxstyle} />
    <br/>
    <br/>
</Canvas>
```

When the Sampledatagrid contains "Adam" it should display a textbox.

Comment: you cant use if-else in Xaml but you can use [Triggers](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF) [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172392/how-to-do-a-simple-xaml-wpf-conditional-binding-on-the-visibility-property)

Comment: Inline `if` statements are not supported in XAML but you can potentially use [data triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.8) or [converters](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) depending on your logic. There is no `Contains` method or operator available in XAML.

Comment: Why do you use `Canvas` in there? Unless you are drawing geometry there is no need for it, as it uses `left` and `top` properties like in middle ages or `WinForms`! Use relative positioning instead also look into `Triggers` beware that triggers can only check for true value only (some property needs to be equal to your condition) no other comparison is possible without usage of Converters.

Comment: Sorry for that Canvas, I know it is old school, But can a Trigger Contain a Value?

Answer (score 0):

First, to let your TextBox show the selected entry of the DataGrid, set its Text-Binding to the corresponding value.

Just add the 'Text' property in the correct way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Sampledatagrid, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="12">
```

Possibly, the name of your variable "SelectedItem.Name" is another one than "Name".

Second, if the TextBox shall only show 'valid' names (like e.g. 'Adam'), I show you how to use a converter to do so.

Create a new file in your project called 'ValidNamesConverter.cs'. This file gets following code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    internal class ValidNamesConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valAsString = value.ToString();

            if (valAsString == "Adam" || valAsString == "Eve")
                return value;

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

In the "Resources" section of your MainWindow.xaml (or UserControl.xaml) add an instance (a static resource) of this converter-class. (if you don't have already a "Resources" section, just add one):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- make a XAML instance of the class ValidNamesConverter -->
    <local:ValidNamesConverter x:Key="validNamesConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, extend the TextBox's Text-Binding to use this converter.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Sampledatagrid, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Converter={StaticResource validNamesConverter}}" Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="42">
```

The converter in this case decides, which string shall be 'forwarded' to the TextBox. So, if a valid name is given into the converter, it will just return that name again. If an invalid name is given, the converter returns an empty string.

Anyway, in my example, the TextBox is always visibly shown. If you want the TextBox to be absent when an invalid name is selected, you probably need a second converter (e.g. ValidNameToVisibilityConverter) which you bind to the TextBox's Visibility-property. That converter then returns either Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed. Within this 2nd converter you can make use of the ValidNamesConverter to avoid having a set of valid names twice in your code.