# Attribute Browsable only if another property is set to True

Tags: c#, attributes

I want a property to be display only if another boolean property is set to true.

I don't know how to create this dinamically visulization. The property browsable is waiting a bool value

There is no problem to this property be serialized or not.

```
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
[Display(Name = "Checked")]
public bool IsChecked{ get; set; } = true;
    
[DataMember(Order = 2)]
[Display(Name = "Address")]
[IsBrowseable(IsChecked)]
public string Address{ get; set; }
```

Comment: How do you want to display it (HTML, Winforms, WPF, ..) what have you tried so far and what's the problem?

Comment: Hello @ChristophLütjen, I'm trying to apply it on a WPF application. I only tried to find a attribute that could be good, as this browsable. With the browsable as the way I've added it show an error "An object reference is required  for the non- static field"

Comment: I'm can't help you with WPF, but from a quick search, this looks like it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172392/how-to-do-a-simple-xaml-wpf-conditional-binding-on-the-visibility-property - if not: It often helps, if you add your XAML code too to allow readers here to fully understand your problem. It's really important to re-read questions on SO and check if other have a chance to understand it without knowing anything from your project except what you provided in you question.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, in this case the attribute argument value must be a compile-time constant.
Changing IsChecked while the application is running would not affect the attribute anyhow, so in your case doing `[IsBrowseable(true)]` would have the same result as using the IsChecked property with it's default value.

For more information check out [MSDN's C# language specification for attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes) which states the following:

> An expression `E` is an attribute_argument_expression if all of the
> following statements are true:
>
> - The type of `E` is an attribute parameter type (Attribute parameter types).
> - At compile-time, the value of `E` can be resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A constant value.
>   - A `System.Type` object.
>   - A one-dimensional array of attribute_argument_expressions.